# How to remove a tween with createjs

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, createjs, tween, tween.js

I have a clock hand that rotates as a timer. If the user completed activity before the time runs out I need to stop that tween.

I tried remove tween with no luck. What am I doing wrong?

I get into my levelup function but the remove tween does not work.

```
 function Clock() {
            //    this.board = board;
            clockContainer = new createjs.Container();
            contain = new createjs.Container();
            var clockBack = new createjs.Bitmap(queue.getResult("clockBack"));
            clockHand = new createjs.Bitmap(queue.getResult("clockHand"));
            clockBack.x = 40;
            clockBack.y = 480;
            clockHand.x = 95;
            clockHand.y = 539;
            clockHand.regX = 20
            clockHand.regY = 105;
            clockHand.scaleX = clockHand.scaleY = 0.50;
            clockBack.scaleX = clockBack.scaleY = 0.50;
            clockContainer.addChild(clockBack, clockHand);
            TimerLength = 30000;
            stage.addChild(clockContainer)
            mytweentodisable = createjs.Tween.get(clockHand, { loop: false }).to({ rotation: 360 }, TimerLength).call(function () {
                //this will trigger the timer is up
                GamehasEnded = true;
                checkWrongAndRight();
            });
        }

  function levelUp() {

            createjs.Tween.removeTweens(mytweentodisable)
            console.log("adding Level up button");
            levelUpContainer = new createjs.Container();
            levelUpIcon = new createjs.Bitmap(queue.getResult("levelUp"));
            levelUpContainer.addChild(levelUpIcon);
            stage.addChild(levelUpContainer)
            levelUpContainer.x = 350
            levelUpContainer.y = 500
            levelUpContainer.addEventListener("click", function () {
                console.log("clicked it");
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

`mytweentodisable.setPaused(true);`

Comment: My boss is a big fan of yours!

Comment: Tell him I said hi. :)

Comment: As far as I understand the implementation, `setPaused()` actually removes references from inside the library to the tween, so the tween will be garbage collected provided a user also has no references. This was not obvious for me, when I saw the method name. I was looking for an instance method called something like `remove()`.